# Выпадающий список категорий в админке Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Никак не могу найти решение...
В меню "Все товары" товары можно сортировать по категориям, но, чтобы выбрать категорию, нужно ввести первые три буквы, это очень неудобно.
Подскажите пожалуйста, как можно сделать выпадающим списком где видны категории и под-категории?

Заранее большое спасибо!

Answer (score 0):

Проблему решил плагин **Admin Columns**